# Fatal error initializing plugin com.android.tools.ndk

Tags: android

I'm attempting to create my first project in Android Studio, and I'm encountering an IDE Fatal Error.

I've disabled the Android APK Support plugin along with the Android NDK support plugin, which has allowed me to successfully open a new Android Studio project; however, after a few moments, I'm receiving an IDE Fatal Error notification along with an exception report. This is also causing my layout code to produce multiple errors concurrently, wherein attributes and elements in my layout code are "not allowed here". I've tried invalidating caches and restarting, but it didn't fix the problem.

```
java.lang.Throwable: Assertion failed: Duplicate bundled template Gradle Build Script with wrapper.gradle [jar:file:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-common.jar!/fileTemplates/internal/Gradle Build Script with wrapper.gradle.ft, jar:file:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar!/fileTemplates/internal/Gradle Build Script with wrapper.gradle.ft]
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.assertTrue(Logger.java:186)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.FTManager.createAndStoreBundledTemplate(FTManager.java:198)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.FTManager.setDefaultTemplates(FTManager.java:187)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.FileTemplatesLoader.<init>(FileTemplatesLoader.java:88)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.FileTemplateSettings.<init>(FileTemplateSettings.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:92)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceManagerImpl.java:222)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.lambda$getComponentInstance$0(ServiceManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:187)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:211)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:118)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:89)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceManagerImpl.java:222)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.lambda$getComponentInstance$0(ServiceManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:586)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:192)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:211)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:30)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.FileTemplateManager.getInstance(FileTemplateManager.java:54)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.FileTemplateManager.getDefaultInstance(FileTemplateManager.java:67)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidStudioInitializer.setUpNewProjectActions(AndroidStudioInitializer.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidStudioInitializer.run(AndroidStudioInitializer.java:87)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:201)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:92)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:586)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:474)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:408)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:394)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:217)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.lambda$initApplication$0(IdeaApplication.java:77)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:349)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I synced my project with the Gradle files, and although it failed, it removed the multiple errors in my layout code.